# Вывод результата поиска на страницу Php

Tags: php, mysql

Я не силен в *php*, прошу помочь мне с таким вопросом.

Есть задача: сделать сайт с поиском по БД.

Поиск я реализовал, все работает, но нужно, чтобы кликнув на один из результатов поиска, меня выбивало на страницу-шаблон, в которой бы выводилась вся информация из данного ряда, т.е заголовок, описание, изображение... Вывести все в цикле я понимаю как, но как сделать, чтобы выводилась инфа той ссылки из поиска, на которую я кликнул?

Comment: Всем спасибо, вы мне очень помогли, теперь все работает))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос достаточно абстрактный...

1. Вы сделали поиск.
2. Находите много каких-то элементов, у каждого есть Id.
3. При перечеслении всех элементов **вы** формируете ссылку для
   просмотра этого элемента, например:

   ```
   echo '<a href="/show.php?id="' . $row['id'] . '...</a>';
   ```
4. При клике на ссылку вы попадаете в созданный **вами** скрипт-файл
   php (тут show.php)
5. В этом файле вы получаете одну строку (row) зная Id ( `$_GET['id']`
   ) и всё там и выводите:

   ```
   echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['name'] . .....;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Очень расплывчивый вопрос.

Такое можно сделать многими способами. Например:

1. Результат поиска это ссылка вида `{ваш сайт}/?res={идентификатор строки поиска}`
2. После клика на такой линк, запрос переходит на ваш скрипт, где вы **сначала хорошо фильтруете запрос от всяких иньекций**, а потом берете `{идентификатор строки поиска}` и на основании него возвращаете шаблон с релевантной информацией

Answer (score 0):

тебе нужно разобраться с тем, что такое get, post запросы. Тогда все поймешь. Ссылка на запись должна быть с  id этой записи из БД, далее при переходе на страницу берешь id (из адресной строки, это get запрос) и ищешь нужную информацию в БД. Самый быстрый и оптимальный вариант.